# How to refactor "if" statement into an "unless" statement?

Tags: ruby

Is there any way to refactor this into an `unless` statement?

```
a = false
b = true

if !a or !b
  puts "hello world"
end
```

This doesn't seem  to be equivalent

```
unless a or b
  puts "hello world"
end
```

Comment: Maybe try: `puts "hello world" unless (a || b)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Negating your condition according to [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)...

```
unless (a and b)
```

Answer (score 3):

That should be:

```
puts "hello" unless a and b
```

Or

```
unless a and b
   puts "hello"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As `unless` is the negation of `if`, you need to negate the whole condition expression (you can use [De Morgan’s laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to simplify it):

```
!(!a or !b) ≡ !!a and !!b ≡ a and b
```

So:

```
unless a or b
  puts "hello world"
end
```