# If statement is always true

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

Have the following If statement that should only allow the sub to continue if User_ID = 1 or the User_ID = the author ID.

When debugging I know that the first part is true (the user ID is 1), but it still trips the popup.

Stared at this for a while - must have brain fog as it looks like it should work as intended

```
If (Not User_ID = 1 OrElse Not User_ID = WL_UserID) Then
    AppBoxValidation("Only the original author can edit this item!")
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: I agree with Yuriy. I used to get in major trouble on the AND versus OR in If statements Even though logically it was right the If was looking for a different format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Readability is an important attribute of code:

```
If (User_ID = 1 Or User_ID = WL_UserID) Then
   'continue
Else 
   AppBoxValidation("Only the original author can edit this item!")
   Exit Sub
End If
```

Alernatively, you could write:

```
If (User_ID <> 1 AndAlso User_ID <> WL_UserID) Then
   AppBoxValidation("Only the original author can edit this item!")
   Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: I was being lazy and just wanted to insert something at the beginning of the code.... Thank you

Comment: Re the edited version  - I tried that first before the NOT prefix and it still threw up the pop-up - that was what threw me out

Answer (score 2):

If `Not User_ID = 1` is false (because `User_ID = 1` is false), then `Not User_ID = WL_UserID` is true. That's all there is to it .. *but*, the logic error can be seen as follows.

The initial expression,

```
Not User_ID = 1 OrElse Not User_ID = WL_UserID
```

can be rewritten as

```
Not (User_ID = 1 AndAlso User_ID = WL_UserID)
```

by application of [De Morgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws). This reads as: "It is not the case that User_ID is 1 *and* User_ID is WL_UserID". Assuming that `1 <> WL_UserID`, then the inner AndAlso expression is always false (as User_ID cannot be equal to two different values at once) and the entire expression is true - always.

On way to solve the original, which is what I recommend, is to have *one* Not on the outside:

```
Not (User_ID = 1 OrElse User_ID = WL_UserID)
```

The changed expression reads as: "It is not the case that User_Id is 1 *or* User_Id is WL_UserID".

However, taking the now correct expression, it is trivial to transform it back to an equivalent with the Not's inside, again by application of DM. (I'm not a fan of this construct and avoid it most of the time.)

```
Not User_ID = 1 AndAlso Not User_ID = WL_UserID
```

Or, with transformation of the comparison operators (`Not x = y` -> `x <> y`),

```
User_ID <> 1 AndAlso User_ID <> WL_UserID
```

---

- [How to understand De Morgan Laws Boolean Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127694/how-to-understand-de-morgan-laws-boolean-expression)
- [How to refactor "if" statement into an "unless" statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665883/how-to-refactor-this-if-statement-into-an-unless-statement) (Ruby, same idea)
- [Else If and Do while does not work as intended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632725/else-if-and-do-while-does-not-work-as-intended) (Java, same idea)

Comment: `AndThen` ? Please tell me that's a typo.

Answer (score 1):

As it is if the current User_ID is not 1 or if the User_ID is not equal to WL_USERID then the popup will appear.
But from your description it sounds like it should be
if the User_ID = 1 or User_ID = WL_UserID then show the pop-up

```
If (User_ID = 1 OrElse User_ID = WL_UserID) Then
    AppBoxValidation("Only the original author can edit this item!")
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd write it this way: "if the user is not the admin, and the user is not the author", disallow the action.

```
If (User_ID <> 1 AndAlso User_ID <> WL_UserID) Then
    AppBoxValidation("Only the original author can edit this item!")
    Exit Sub
End If
```

This clearly shows the logic, and is shorter.

Answer (score 0):

If the user ID is 1, `Not User_ID =1` will evaluate to `false`, and the code to the right of the `OrElse` will be evaluated. See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ea1sssb2.aspx) on the `OrElse` operator, specifically the Remarks section.